# Unnecessary Hoisting is happening.! why?

Tags: javascript

```
function test() {
    a = 10;
    alert(a);
    if (false) {
        var a;
    }
}

test();
```

From the above code, you can see I have declared one variable inside a falsy if statement, meaning the code inside it would not executed. See, now that variable is unnecessary hoisted, why is it so..? It would unnecessarily allocate memory. Isn't the compiler clever enough to identify it..? Or would those variables get collected in a garbage like java.?

The given code block would get interpreted as,

```
function test() {    
    var a;
    a = 10;
    alert(a);
    if (false) {   
    }    
}

test();
```

Logically what's the use of hoisting a variable away from a falsy statement.? If `var a;` allocates any memory internally, then this is not an optimized one right..?

Comment: All variables have function scope. Every `var` statement is always hoisted to the top of the function it is declared in, always.

Comment: What do you mean "unnecessarily allocate memory"? It uses the same amount of memory whether or not it is hoisted.

Comment: @soktinpk so what would happen if we execute a code `var a;` won't it allocate any memory for it..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It allocates memory whether or not one uses `var a`. That is, (see @Brad's answer), the variable will become global (attatched to the `window` object).

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Hoisting has nothing to do with the runtime. Think of it a reordering of statements when the JS parsed.

Comment: Declaration of variables happens at compile time, not run time. Therefore it doesn't matter whether the `if` block actually runs; the variable is still declared. And I also agree with Tim (variables have function scope) and Brad (even if you didn't declare it, it would use the global scope, which in this case would give exactly the same output).

Comment: @cookiemonster but i thought we have locked the reordering by means of providing a falsy if statement...

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but any `var` statement gets moved to the top. Always. No exceptions. Doesn't matter what you put around it.

Comment: The *condition* of the `if` statement is evaluated at runtime. The "reordering" is done when the code is parsed. No matter what, the `var` will be moved to the top of the enclosing function.

Comment: @cookiemonster Does this line `var a;`, allocates any memory internally.?

Comment: I don't know. Does it matter? Modern engines have very good optimizations, so if there's some variable that can be proven to be unused, then I'd bet that it would get optimized away. Ultimately, if you wanted `a="foo"` to be a guaranteed global, do `window.a="foo"`. But I don't know that you'll gain efficiency.

Comment: ...ultimately you don't have the fine-grained control over memory that you have in C. It's good to be conservative on memory usage in JS, but not at that level. Let the JS engine worry about that.

Comment: @cookie monster, I'm not sure I'm so optimistic about the compiler's ability to optimise in this case. How would it know that there wasn't another script somewhere that accessed the global variable, perhaps dynamically? Having said that, it's really not worth worrying about it :-)

Comment: @DavidKnipe: I'm not sure what you mean. There are no optimizations for global variables for that very reason. I just meant that if he was trying to create a global, but the `var` was getting in the way, then he would need to be explicit in its declaration. He may be thinking that a global will get rid of the need to allocation every time the function is called, and that's probably true, but it doesn't mean it'll be more efficient overall.

Comment: @cookie monster Sorry, I misunderstood you, I thought you meant that it might change global variables to local or vice versa. If you just meant that it would (probably) ignore a declaration if the variable was unused and not assign memory, then I agree.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Ah, yeah that's what I meant. The scope won't change, but they should be able to get rid of variables in a local scope that are proven to never be used. I'd bet that they can do it to some degree at runtime as well, like if a variable is only used behind a boolean provided as an argument, I'd imagine that they would avoid the allocation, but I don't know enough about compilers to be certain.

Comment: Note this is not the same as garbage collection. Garbage collection happens at run time, and destroys objects which have been created by the running of the process.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: In terms of memory usage, I guess it would be better to think of `var` as mere syntax *defining* scope (keeping in mind hoisting rules) but not allocatiing, and the `=` as being the actual allocation of memory. I think it's a pretty safe bet that that's actually the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mozilla's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) talks more about variable hoisting

You'll notice that

```
function test() {
  a = 10;
  alert("Function a=" + a);
  if (false) {
    var a;
  }
}

test();
alert("Global a=" + a);
```

gives an error of not defined for a on the "Global" line that because of scoping, you will not get on

```
function test() {
  a = 10;
  alert("Function a=" + a);
}

test();
alert("Global a=" + a);
```

So, from the explanation in the docs, your code is equal to:

```
function test() {
  var a;
  a = 10;
  alert(a);
  if (false) {
  }
}

test();
```

as the declaration is processed before any other code is executed.

Comment: good answer - up-voted. I would just add the bit when you say `gives and error` for something like outputs undefined.

Comment: @bitoiu - actually it doesn't output `undefined`.  It gives an error: `ReferenceError: a is not defined`.  You can see that in the console when running this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LHe8U/.  That's what happens if you try to access non-existent global variables unless you qualify them like `window.a` which would be `undefined`.

Comment: I believe browsers output `undefined`, but nodejs gives the ReferenceError.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Browsers too will always halt the current execution immediately when trying to read a variable that isn't reachable from the current scope. It's only when *setting* non-existent variables that JS will allow it to be used, creating a global (though not in strict mode).

Comment: [Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) says "If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception."  That's what I get in Chrome when I tested before writing the answer.

Comment: JeremyMiller: I think people fall into the trap of testing in the console without refreshing the environment between tests, so that a previous test that did create a global is now affecting the current test. I know I've done that plenty of times.

Comment: @cookiemonster Excellent point.  Since I always spawn a new, empty tab, I forget about that.  How we test is as important as what we test.